# how to combine and compare two variables dynamically in bash?

Tags: bash

i have variable `$var` and `$var2`. I created a random number via `rand=$((RANDOM % 10))`.

now if I want to combine `$var` and `$var2` and assign value of `$rand` to them:-

```
#! /bin/bash

rand=$((RANDOM % 10))
var2=1

var_$var2="$rand"
```

And i want to compare them too:-

```
[[ $var_$var2 -eq 0 ]] && echo "Its zero"
```

This obviously doesn't work, then how exactly can I declare and Compare two variable dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of choices.

Do to exactly what you want, you can use the `eval` statement to take the result of an expression and execute it as a shell command. For example:

```
eval selected=\$x$randomnum
if [[ $selected == $player ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

The expression passed to the `eval` statement becomes `selected=$x1`, which we then evalute, setting `selected` to the value of `$x1`.

---

But a better structure for this would be to use an array variable instead of a series of named variables, something like:

```
randomnum=$(( RANDOM % 10 ))
x=( 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 )
player1 = 1

if [[ ${x[$randomnum]} == $player1 ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this :-

```
#!/bin/bash

a='1'
b=5
c="${a}${b}"
echo $c

d=15

if [[ $c == $d ]]; then
        echo "it end!"
    fi
```